# Linear algebra question how to prove $\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^n=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a n by n matrix which has $\lambda$ as eigenvalue.

In my text book,
if we let $\delta_k=\dim \ker(A-\lambda I)^k$

then $\delta_1\leq\delta_2\leq\cdots\leq\delta_n=n$.

Actually it is clear $\delta_k\leq\delta_{k+1}$
because $$v\in \ker(A-\lambda I)^k\Rightarrow (A-\lambda I)^kv=0\Rightarrow(A-\lambda I)^{k+1}v=0 \Rightarrow v\in \ker(A-\lambda I)^{k+1}.$$

But I don't know how to prove why $\delta_n=n$.
Please give me some help.

Comment: Note $\delta_n=n$ if and only if $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ in the algebraic closure.  Your phrasing would only imply $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, not that it's the only one.

Comment: You  need more than the assumptions you have. Consider $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$, and $\lambda=1$. Then $A-I = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)$, and $(A-I)^k = A-I$ for all $k\geq 0$. Your $\delta_i$ are always equal to $1$, never equal to $2$.